# How can I resolve Integrity Constraint violation in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-blade

Here is my teachers migrations file:

```
$table->id();
$table->unsignedbiginteger('level_id');
$table->foreign('level_id')->references('id')->on('levels');
$table->string('teacher_name'); 
$table->string('teacher_email')->unique();           
$table->string('teacher_home_phone');
$table->string('teacher_mobile_phone');
$table->string('teacher_work_phone');
$table->string('teacher_home_address');
$table->string('teacher_suburb');
$table->string('teacher_postcode');
$table->string('teacher_username');
$table->string('teacher_password');                      
$table->timestamps();
```

Here is the levels migrations file:

```
$table->bigIncrements('id');            
    $table->string('level_name');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Teachers form.blade.php:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-5">                    
    <label for="teacher_levels" class="required">Mention levels Instructor's going to teach </label>                
    <div class="col-md-12">                                
        @foreach($levels as $level)                
        <div class="form-check form-check-inline col-md-3">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="level_id[]" value="{{@$level->level_id}}" 
                    @if(isset($level->level_id) && @in_array('', @$level->level_id)) {{'checked'}} @endif>
            <label class="form-check-label">{{@$level->level_id}}</label>                            
        </div>
        @endforeach
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my teachers model.php:

```
class Teacher extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $fillable= ['level_id','teacher_name','teacher_email',
                            'teacher_home_phone','teacher_work_phone',
                            'teacher_mobile_phone','teacher_home_address',
                            'teacher_suburb', 'teacher_postcode',
                            'teacher_username', 'teacher_password',];

    public function levels()
    {
        return $this-> belongsTo(Levels::class, 'level_id');
    }                     
}
```

This is my levelsmodel.php

```
class Levels extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public function teacher()
    {
        return $this -> hasMany(Teacher::class);
    }

}
```

Here is my TeacherController.php:

```
class TeacherController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance
     * 
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard
     * 
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Renderable
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $teachers= Teacher::all();
        $levels = Levels::all();
        return view('admin.teachers.list', compact('teachers', 'levels'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard
     * 
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Renderable
     */
    public function add()
    {
        $teacher = array();
        $levels = Levels::all();
        return view('admin.teachers.add', compact('teacher', 'levels'));
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage
     * 
     * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //get form data
        $data = $request->all();

        //Check if teacher is already registered
        $teacher = Teacher::where('teacher_email', $data['teacher_email'])->first();

        //Teacher Check
        if($teacher){
            return redirect()->back()->with('error', 'Teacher is already registered, please check teacher email!');

        }
        

        //Handle Teacher''s level data
        $levels = Levels::all();

        //Check if teacher is already registered
        $user = User::where('email', $data['teacher_email'])->first();

        //User Check
        if($user){
            return redirect()->with('error', 'Teacher email is already registered, please check teacher email');

        }

        //Create Teacher Record
        $teacher = Teacher::create($data);

        //Create User
        $user = User::create([
            'name' => $data['teacher_name'],
            'email' => $data['teacher_email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['teacher_password'])
        ]);

        //Assign Above Teacher Role
        $user->assignRole('Teacher');

        //Update teacher column
        $teacher->update([
            'teacher_id' => $teacher->id
        ]);

        if(isset($data['save_close']) && $data['save_close']){
            return redirect()-> route('teacher.index')->with('message', 'Teacher information is saved successfully! ');
        }elseif(isset($data['save_add']) && $data['save_add']){
            return redirect()->back()->with('message','Teacher information is saved successfully!');
        }
    }
    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource
     * 
     * @param int $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */

     public function edit($id)
     {
        $teachers = Teacher::find($id);
        $levels = Levels::all();
        if($teacher){
            //Teacher Level Convert to Array
            if($teachers->level_id){
                $teachers->level_id = (json_decode($teachers->level_id));
            }
            return view('admin.teachers.edit', compact('teacher', 'levels'));
        }else{
            aboort(404);
        }

        
     }
     
      /**
       * Update the specified resource from url teachers/lists
       * 
       * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request
       * @param int $id
       * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response 
       */
      public function update(Request $request, $id)
      {
        //get form data
        $data = $request->all();

        //Get Teacher Record
        $teacher = Teacher::find($id);
        $teacher->fill($data)->save();

        //Update Password
        if(isset($data['teacher_password']) && $data['teacher_password']){
            $user = User::where('email', $teacher->teacher_email)->first();
            $user->update([
                'password' => Hash::make($data['teacher_password'])
            ]);
        }

        if(isset($data['save_close']) && $data['save_close']){
            return redirect()->route('teacher.index')->with('message', 'Teacher information updated successfully!');
        }elseif(isset($data['save_add']) && $data['save_add']){
            return redirect()->back()->with('message', 'Teacher information updated successfully!');
        }

      }

      /**
       * Remove the specified resource from storage
       * 
       * @param int $id
       * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
       */
      public function delete($id)
      {
        // Delete the row pointed to by teacher ID
        $teacher = Teacher::findorFail($id);
        //Find User
        $user = User::find($teacher->teacher_id);
        if($user){
            $user->removeRole('Teacher');
            //Delete Teacher
            
            $teacher->delete();
            //Delete User
            $user->delete();
        }else{
            //Delete Teacher
            $teacher->delete();
        }

        return redirect()->route('teacher.index');
      }
}
```

When I click on the save and close buttons I get this error:   Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'level_id' cannot be null. I need some help on how can I resolve this issue. One Teacher can teach multiple levels and Multiple levels are taught by one teacher. I want it to be displayed in the listing.
[attributes of levels tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mv7sc.png)

Comment: In your migration file, the `level_id` foreign key is not defined as `nullable` and therefore requires a value when storing a record. Where and how are you populating that field when you store a record?

Comment: I don't want it defined as nullable as it contains vlues of levels when teacher defines which levels he is going to teach once he clicks those checkboxes. Each checkboxes consists of name and id

Comment: That's my point. If it's not nullable and you're getting a violation constraint error the `level_id` field requires a valid value (i.e. not null and the id exists in the `levels` table). You need to populate that association.

Comment: id is definedin levels migrations tables and in teachers migrations tables I have referenced it as foreign key constraint

Comment: You're not reading what I am saying. Your migration file is not the problem, you need to actually populate the `level_id` field when you're storing the record. The error you're getting is telling you that you're currently not doing that.

Comment: I have populated it via seeder.

Comment: You're getting this error when you **save** a record. This is **not** related to your migration or seeder, the error is with your **save** method. Add where and how you save the form data to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `$level->level_id` to `$level->id`

```
@foreach($levels as $level)                
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline col-md-3">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="level_id" value="{{ $level->id }}" @checked($level->id == old('level_id'))>
        <label class="form-check-label">{{ $level->id }}</label>                            
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Comment: I am still getting the same error when I changed level_id to $level->id

Comment: Then how can I overcome it when it is throwing exceptions?

Comment: How can I resolve this it?

Comment: What is the solution to this problem as I am new to laravel?

Comment: @MuhammadOmer, also removed `@` from `@$level->id`,  `@in_array('', @$level->id)`. And `@in_array('', @$level->id)` wrong implemented.

Comment: inside there are values of levels tables like id, levels_name

Comment: It is giving me type error: in_array(): Argument #2 ($haystack) must be of type array, int given

Comment: I have attached the screen shot with blue hyperlink

Comment: It is displaying id of levels table

Comment: It is displaying only id of levels when I insert it. it shows me Id of the last levels of integer

Comment: I want display of data from multiple levels id table which is displayed as a foreign key on teachers tables

Comment: I am using Laravel 9.0

Comment: Levels tables id is a foreign key on teachers tables backend side of code. while on the frontend side of code I have assigned checbox values of levels to tables form.blade.php

Comment: Yes but it gives only one value of levels id

Comment: Checboxes are not shown